# Can I just return a finally from a function that returns a promise?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have this function:

```
archive= (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    return self.setStatus()
        .then(
            () => { }
            )
        .finally(() => {
            self.controls = self.getFilteredTestStatusActions(1, 'Admin');
        });
};
```

I would like to set the controls after this function succeeds or gives an error. In this case do I even need the .then construct ?

Comment: I think `finally` is defined as `then(callback, callback)` with the same callback function for both resolved and rejected routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this case do I even need the .then construct

*No*. You don't need it in this case. `finally` will be called irrespective of `then`.